# installing bootstrap 3 via package.json

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, npm, npm-install

I'm reading in all documentation that I can run `npm install bootstrap@3` how do I put this in my `package.json` file?

`"bootstrap": "3.3.7"` <= doesn't work

`"bootstrap@3": "3.3.7"` <= doesn't work

From bootstrap site:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

From create-react-app site:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-bootstrap

Comment: don't know what I was doing wrong.  `"bootstrap": "3.3.7"` worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just put bootstrap and version that you want, like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
  },
```

After that run:

```
npm install
```